# How to: Export data from Magento 1.x and import in 2.0?

Tags: magento2, magento2-migration-tool

What is the default way to migrate data from a Magento 1.6.1 shop to a Magento 2.0 shop? I want to migrate the orders including all the invoices and shipments, the customers including their passwords and of course the products.

Can I use the dataflow export and then import that in Magento 2 or are there migration tools available? I know there is the official tool (https://github.com/magento/data-migration-tool), but maybe there is something else out there?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Uberthemes makes a magento 2 module that handles this pretty well. You'll need your credentials for the databases on both ends. The github page is pretty straight forward.

Check it out:

https://github.com/ubertheme/module-ubdatamigration/blob/master/README.md

Answer (score 1):

I think you need create a script for export data from magento 1 and import to magento 2. I try extension https://github.com/magento/data-migration-tool in many time but was not success. Because our database very big and many attribute. Good luck